# getting error when inserting driver module

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, kernel

error as can not be  read private key when I install driver Realtek driver module to linux ubuntu 14.04  (3.13-.0-32-generic) how to resolve this problem . can i downgrade my kernel version of current to previous version like 2.16.x.x ?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5JFgCqLfkeMTmhaVF9ZaHVYS3c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: "Can't read private key" in this context, is trivial. It will not keep the module from working as expected. Does it?

Comment: it is not insering module..hi chill i read all your solutions please give me replay to my previous question if possible

Comment: i want to connect wired connection but it automatically disconnceting and connecting after some time

Comment: Did you reboot? Is the module loaded then? `lsmod | grep r81` Does it disconnect even with the new module?

Comment: yes,still it connects itself and disconnects automatically even i reboot the system.I given an image when i installing r8168 module where it is giving error as can not be read private key.what is that error? is it possible to connect with new module even after that error?

Comment: It certainly is possible. Which module is loaded? r8169, r8168 or both? `lsmod`.  Which version did you compile? r8168-xx-what??

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/600780/ubuntu-not-detecting-wired-connection-and-automatically-disconnecting

Comment: above link is my wired conection network problem there driver details are not given when i see connection information

Comment: Please see my comments above. In order to help you, I need the information requested. Please re-read and respond.

Comment: yes driver version r8168-8.039.00 and image after lsmod command is below link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5JFgCqLfkeMdTBubzRWcUZnblE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: finally,i want to configure my wired ethernet connection with my pc.whatever the way you have to configure that tell me pleaseee :chili

Answer (score 0):

You have both r8169 and r8168 loaded. I suspect you will have a better result blacklisting r8169. From a terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist r8169"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r r8169
exit
```

Any improvement? It may take a reboot.

If further steps are required, I will edit my answer here.

Your blacklist file appears corrupted. Please do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Remove all the lines below but not including:

```
blacklist r8169
```

The last several lines of the file should now read:

```
# EDAC driver for amd76x clashes with the agp driver preventing the aperture
# from being initialised (Ubuntu: #297750). Blacklist so that the driver
# continues to build and is installable for the few cases where its
# really needed.
blacklist amd76x_edac

blacklist r8169
```

Don't change anything above that point. Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. Reboot.

Now check:

```
lsmod
```

r8168 only and *not* r8169 should be loaded.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22363/discussion-on-answer-by-chili555-getting-error-when-inserting-driver-module).

Comment: it is not working. on statup it is showing the message  that /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file is not loaded successfully and corrupted. even only one driver is loading when i check with lsmod still networking is not connecting

Comment: As @Mitch suggests, please join me in chat.